# Cruise control not working in 6th gear on Peugeot 5008

Tags: peugeot, cruise-control

Does anyone knows what would be wrong with my cruise control in a Peugeot 5008. It works normally in 4th and 5th gear, but it doesn't want to work in 6th gear.

Comment: Is it a manual or automatic gearbox?

Answer (score 3):

Your Peugeot cruise control is 'speed sensitive'. Sixth gear cruise control requires a road speed of 70-75 MPH. The gearbox computes the gear required to maintain a given road speed, if you select a gear to high for the speed you are doing cruise control is switched 'off', to prevent the engine from labouring.